# Service ScheduleTask isn't started in constant intervals

Tags: java, android, service, scheduled-tasks, intervals

I have a service that needs to compare previous and current html code.

I have configured it to do its work every 1 hour, but it actually does it in weird unlinear intervals. I have added to the code a command to write a log file in order to see whenever the work is done. The result is weird: sometimes the interval is less than an hour, sometimes much more (2-3 hours), and sometimes really 1 hour... **edit: when the interval is shorter (1 minute) it operates normally** here's my code:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    doServiceWork();
                    check("SLeEPING!!!", c);
                }
                else {
                    check ("NO INTERNET", c);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {check("78", c);}
        }
    }, 1, 3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Comment: You've submitted this question twice. I can see 3! questions covering the same topic. In general a question is never 'dead', please work on your first question related to this topic and remove the two remaining ones... Hint: try to reduce the amount of code provided in your question, just provide the relevant parts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Service ScheduleTask itn't started in constant intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662034/service-scheduletask-itnt-started-in-constant-intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AlarmManager. You are making the thread sleep which I am not sure Android guarantees it will work that way. Something like this should help you. This will start the service every hour:

```
PendingIntent serviceIntent= PendingIntent.getService(context,
                    0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), 0);

            long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            long currenciesIntervalInSec = 3600;

            if (automaticCurrencies)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, firstTime, currenciesIntervalInSec*1000, serviceIntent);
```

Edit:

You should extend IntentService. It takes care of the threads and everything is done in the background (Its particulary useful if you need to do things in the background and you don't need several threads at the same time). Whatever you put in HandleIntent will be executed when you start the service. Internally it will keep a list of the queue.

For example this is a simple service class(You NEED to create both constructors):

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    public MyService(String name) {
        super(name);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

               if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    doServiceWork();
                    check("SLeEPING!!!", c);
                }
                else {
                    check ("NO INTERNET", c);
                }

        }
}
```

Also, you need to add this in your manifest (Of course with your own package):

```
<service android:name="com.services.MyService"/>
```

Comment: Well, I didn't understand how I apply it to my code. Can you tell me what to replace?

Comment: Okay! ill check it for a couple of hours and I will tell you if it worked

Comment: Sure. The first time you run the code it should run right away since the you are setting the first time as the present time. This will run every one hour even if your app is not running. You can also cancel the schedule calling the cancel method on the AlarmManager passing the same intent.

Comment: Other thing. Inner classes are collected much often. If that doesn't work, try creating a new runnable class, a proper variable and then use it on the service using you original code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you activity is destroyed by the Android task Manager and it is not shutdown by the timer. This is why you are getting shorter values. And this is why, when setting a very low value, you don't get that.

You should read about how Android handles the Processes and applications [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/multitasking-android-way.html).

Comment: No. it is absolutely not this. I thought about it so i tracked for how long the service is running, and its running for hours without interuption...